# Writing data to dynamoDB with lambda in an Alexa skill

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I have a lambda function that is connected to an Alexa skill. At the start of the skill I want to store a string to dynamoDB. Therefore I call a function directly in the launch request (the function is called nameExport()). 
However the function is only stores something if I delete the "this.emit" command in the launch request. If I leave "this.emit" the skill is working but nothing is stored to the database. Below you find the code concerning LaunchRequest as well as the function to store into dynamoDB.

```
var config = require("config");
var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var Speech = require("ssml-builder");
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

let handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        nameExport("testName");
        let speech = new Speech ();
        speech.say("Welcome by Emotions.")
        speech.pause("100ms")
        speech.say("Do you want to assess your current emotion?")
        let speechOutput = speech.ssml(true);
        this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
    },
    'Emotion': function () {
        let speech = new Speech();
        ...
```

The nameExport function that should write the String into the database:

```
function nameExport(name) {
    var tableName = "myinfo";
    dynamodb.putItem({
            "TableName": tableName,
            "Item": {
                "name": {
                    "S": name
                }
            }
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                //context.fail('ERROR: Dynamo failed: ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('Dynamo Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
                //context.succeed('SUCCESS');
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.emit` just finishes lambda execution and `putItem` function cannot be finished in its scope. You should call `this.emit` when `putItem` finishes.

You can achieve that by using `async/await` (make sure, that lambda uses node.js v8.10):

```
'LaunchRequest': async function () {
        await nameExport("testName");
        let speech = new Speech ();
        speech.say("Welcome by Emotions.")
        speech.pause("100ms")
        speech.say("Do you want to assess your current emotion?")
        let speechOutput = speech.ssml(true);
        this.emit(":ask", speechOutput)
    },
```

```
async function nameExport(name) {
    var tableName = "myinfo";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { dynamodb.putItem({
            "TableName": tableName,
            "Item": {
                "name": {
                    "S": name
                }
            }
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Dynamo Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
                resolve();
            }
        })});
};
```

Or without `async/await` by emitting ":ask" in callback, which is not so gentle solution:

```
'LaunchRequest': function () {

        let speech = new Speech ();
        speech.say("Welcome by Emotions.")
        speech.pause("100ms")
        speech.say("Do you want to assess your current emotion?")
        let speechOutput = speech.ssml(true);
        nameExport("testName", () => this.emit(":ask", speechOutput));
    },
```

```
function nameExport(name, callback) {
    var tableName = "myinfo";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { dynamodb.putItem({
            "TableName": tableName,
            "Item": {
                "name": {
                    "S": name
                }
            }
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                // some error handling
            } else {
                callback()
            }
        })});
};
```

By the way - there is an [Alexa SDK 2.0](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) - 1.0, that you want to use is no longer supported. I would recommend to switch to the latest version (by re-writing the code or by using an [adapter](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ASK-SDK-Migration-Guide.html))